# How to break up rakefile?

Tags: ruby, octopress, rakefile

I'm trying to add some rake tasks to an Octopress Rakefile, and I'd like to put the tasks in another child rakefile, but when I import the child rakefiles, they can't access the constants at the top of the rakefile.

I'm importing the child rakefile with:

```
Dir.glob('rakefiles/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

This is the sort of config that I'm not able to read in the child file:

```
public_dir      = "public"    # compiled site directory
source_dir      = "source"    # source file directory
blog_index_dir  = 'source'    # directory for your blog's index page (if you put your index in source/blog/index.html, set this to 'source/blog')
```

Here is the error:

> rake aborted! undefined local variable or method `source_dir' for
>   main:Object

Answer (score 2):

You need to use class variables like

```
@public_dir      = "public"    # compiled site directory
@source_dir      = "source"    # source file directory
@blog_index_dir  = 'source'    # directory for your blog's index page (if you put your index in source/blog/index.html, set this to 'source/blog')
```

or constants

```
PUBLIC_DIR      = "public"    # compiled site directory
SOURCE_DIR      = "source"    # source file directory
BLOG_INDEX_DIR  = 'source'    # directory for your blog's index page (if you put your index in source/blog/index.html, set this to 'source/blog')
```

Comment: That kind of breaks my goal of avoiding modification of the Rakefile from Octopress. But I do see how that would work. Any generic way to export the local variables?